# Change Gnome3 standard account to administrator from terminal (Debian)

Tags: debian, gnome3

OS : Debian Jessie 8.5.0

During setup, I defined a password for root and a primary user account.
Now, Gnome has only a standard account with restricted access.
I can't unlock settings, install an application, launch terminal, connect to a new wifi, etc.

I am also not able to manage user accounts since window is locked.
It's asking for an administrator password, root's and any `su`s don't work.

Is there a way to change my primary account type in a terminal logged in as root ? Else, how to create an administrator account in my case ?

Comment: Are you saying that your standard user, can not even open a terminal? (is this correct?)

Comment: edit : I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. The terminals ctrl - alt - fx run fine. When I try to open a terminal from gnome desktop application, I get prompted to enter an administrator password.

Comment: are you starting the terminal by selecting terminal or root-terminal?